# UserWarning: constrain_similarities is set to `False`. It is recommended to set it to `True` when using cross-entropy loss NLU model loaded

Tags: rasa-core, slots, actionform, rasa-sdk

actually I am learning how to build AI chatbot using RASA ,I am doing course from Udemy called : RASA for beginner it's a great course but due to version differences I am facing a problem
when i (run rasa shell) as well as (rasa actions)
so please could anyone help me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aVY7.png)

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem im working with rasa 2.8

i used :

> constrain_similarities: true

in my nlu.yml file and it worked